# Session ends in ASP.NET Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Dears,

I Have an ASPX.Net Application (Framework 4.5.1), It Seems that the session ends every 20 minute, i tried to do the following, but the session still ends after 20 minute.

**In the config file, i add:**

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="60000" cookieless="AutoDetect" mode = "InProc" />
</system.web>
```

**When add new session, i add:**

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 60000;
```

**In the Global Class, i add:**

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Timeout = 60000;
}
```

**Note that** i tried to increase the timeout and decrease it, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Some hosting providers override your config. You can't change that value. I recommend you to use Cookie instead of Session.

If you want to use Session you can use this basic cheat. Add this code block to your MasterPage/Layout. Before add, you need to create an empty page for these requests.

```
<script>
            PingAspToKeepSession();
            function PingAspToKeepSession() {
                var url = "/Session/Refresh";
                var httpOb = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                httpOb.open("POST", url, true);
                httpOb.send("");
                window.setTimeout("PingAspToKeepSession();", 60000); // every 60 seconds
            }
</script>
```

Or you can try to change machine.config:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

Comment: thanks sinan, this issue appears locally (when we run the code from VS), and after hosting, its not related to hosting providers. your example was already tested, but it increase the traffic to the server since we have a huge number of access to our system. i believe that Microsoft and .Net already have a solution for that but i don't now how.

Comment: Did you try to change machine.config?

Comment: @GeorgianCitizen C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

Comment: You need to check "sessionState" property. If is has any value like "timeout=20".. You can change that value.

Comment: @GeorgianCitizen I thought a different solution. If IIS has no request in 20 mins, it stops the worker process. Maybe your session kill when iis stop. You can check the worker process timeout from IIS (application pool)